# jQuery One Div, Two url, using css to make a selection box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As the title says, I got one div containing 2 urls (a).I want to make selection box using jQuery without touching the html, only using the css and script. Can someone help me out?

I was thinking a code like this( I know it doesn;t work):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.language_selection a:last-child').hide();
            $('.language_selection').hover({
                $(this).show();
            });
        })

;
```

Comment: Please be clear about what you want to know.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Could you put a little more detail in your question (less about whether or not you can do it, more about what needs be done)?

Comment: Not really. If you create a selection box, your Html WILL change. Whatd do you want there to happen. Do you want to know how to make a selection box with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you asking for but maybe something like this:

HTML:

```
 <div class="language_selection">
     <a href="#EN">EN</a>
     <a href="#FR">FR</a>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.language_selection a{
    display:none;
}

.language_selection .selected {
    display:block;
    color:red;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.language_selection a:first').addClass('selected');

    $('.language_selection a').click(function() {
        $('.language_selection a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    $('.language_selection').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('a').css('display', 'block');
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('a').not('.selected').hide();
    });

});
```

[FIDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9tRX7/)

An alternative (maybe better ) if you can modify your html with javascript is to just replace the links by a real `select` tag:

```
var select = $('<select></select>');
$('.language_selection a').each(function () {

    var option = $('<option></option>');
    option.val($(this).attr('href')).text($(this).text())
    select.append(option);
});
$('.language_selection').html(select);
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9tRX7/2/)